# Optimising divide operation inside Jacobi relaxation

Tags: c, floating-point, profiling

I am trying to optimise the divide operation from the Jacobi relaxation formula. 
Also doing profiling using perf. 
Here is my code

```
for (int l = 0; l < iter; l++) {
    for (i = 1; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < width; j++) {
            for (k = 1; k < length; k++) {
                float val = 0.0f;
                // Do the Jacobi additions here
                // From profiling, fastest is to fetch k+/-1,j,i
                // Slowest is to fetch k,j,i+/-1


                // Scale with dimensions of the array
                val -= dim * array[k][j][i];

                // Want to optimise this
                val /= 6.0; // profiling shows this as the slowest op

                // Some code here to put the result into the output array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The size of the 3D array can be from 100x100x100 up to 1000x1000x1000. 
I've tried to multiply it to `1.0f/6.0f` but this does not seem to make a difference. The array is a 3D array of floats.

Comment: I think the compiler interprets `val = val  / 6.0` and `val /= 6.0` differently, try the latter and see if there is improvement

Comment: Add `f`  `val = val / 6.0;` --> `val = val / 6.0f;` to avoid `double` math.

Comment: But this is your only operation so far, no? Integer arithmetic and fixed loops can be easily optimized, the only costly instruction there is the floating division.

Comment: Well, of course it is a bottleneck since it is the most complex operation in the code. If you somehow manage to optimize this one, you will complain about something else? And why not to work with scaling factor of `6`? And factor it out afterwards.

Comment: Not posting the "Do the Jacobi additions here" and "code here to put the result" unnecessarily makes this post vague.  Better to post enough code and detail how performance is assessed so others may run it too.

Comment: @Tyler Actually I do `val /= 6.0;` originally, updated the code. The issue still exists though

Comment: @Miguel it is the most costly, next probably would be the scaling with the dimensions of the 3D array, as well as the 3D array fetch from k,j,i+/-1. Not sure if I can optimise it further however

Comment: Have you tried computing and storing `1.0f / 6.0f` outside the loop, and multiplying by that instead of dividing by 6.0?  Floating division is more expensive than floating multiplication, but your compiler might not make this optimization on its own, because it may (very slightly) alter the result.

Comment: The general idea, if this is the more consuming instruction you are close to the best thing you can get. If you put your whole code we can suggest tips to use some parallelism but we can not work blindfolded.

Comment: @JohnBollinger suggestion of converting this to a multiplication may help because there are no DIV/0 checks at any level.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't think a smart compiler will make any difference between `/6.0` or `* (1/6.0)`.

Comment: do the operation outside of the loop and keep it in a variable. this variable may be loaded in the register all the time and there no check for div 0 interruptions. Downside: you may end up propagating a large error during the calculation.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I think you're expressing doubt that a smart compiler would decline to optimize the division to a multiplication by the reciprocal.  Are you then also disagreeing that the two approaches will produce different results for some operands, or are you asserting that compilers will perform the optimization anyway?

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I believe that the compiler *would* optimize the division into the multiplication  in case the division is actually more expensive. If the two approaches might produce different results, it is not of it's concern, as the operations are mathematically equivalent. But surely this is completely implementation specific.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Among the requirements for an optimization to be allowed is that "At program termination, all data written into files shall be **identical** to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced" (C2011, 5.1.2.3/6; emphasis added).  To perform the optimization in question, then, a conforming compiler must be able to prove that it cannot change the output written to any file. At all.  Since it *will* make a difference to the contents of the array elements being computed, a compiler will not generally be able to prove that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Interesting. I wasn't aware of such a requirement.

Comment: @EugeneSh., in practice, this is one of those areas where some compilers may be willfully non-conforming, either by default, or when so instructed by the user, so you might find that your favorite compiler indeed does perform the optimization by default. I'm just saying that it's not safe to assume that it will.